# jQuery - Accordion boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of boxes/blocks of content on a form that need to just show the title of the box, with a 'View More' button below it. When a user clicks View More, the box should expand vertically to show its contents. Also, when another 'View More' is clicked, any other open boxes need to close.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery? I thought maybe I could use the Accordion plugin, but that sounds like it only works with list displays.

Example:

Box Title
View More!

*user clicks

Box Title

- Content
- Content
- Content
- Content

Close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery UI Accordion plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) doesn't rely on lists, you can use markup like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
  <div>First content</div>
  <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
  <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That relies on clicking the title though, and not a button below the title.

Comment: Just set your buttons up to invoke a click on their related header object. Let me know if you need some code for that :-)

Comment: @Kevin: invoke the behavior manually on button click, and e.preventDefault() on title click

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ Look at the theming tab, it doesn't use lists.